# azure pipeline condition always returns false

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I am trying to check if my stage-specific variable `sourceCodeChanged` is equal to `true`.
If it is `true` then the stage should be executed, else it should be skipped.
I can do this by using a `condition` and comparing `sourceCodeChanged` with `true`. this however is not working for me. what am I doing wrong?

This is a snippet out of my azure-pipelines.yml:

```
 - stage: build
   dependsOn: determineChanges
   variables:
     sourceCodeChanged: stageDependencies.determineChanges.checkChanges.outputs['check_changes.SOURCE_CODE_CHANGED']
   condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.sourceCodeChanged, 'true'))
   jobs:
      - job: buildBinaries
        displayName: Build Binaries
        steps:
          - bash: echo $(sourceCodechanged)
            displayName: TestOutPutDeleteMe #debugging step
```

I implemented a debugging step called `TestOutPutDeleteMe`. when the step `TestOutPutDeleteMe` gets executed it prints out `true`, so that means the value gets correctly assigned to `sourceCodeChanged`.
If I try to use the variable sourceCodeChanged in the eq() function it always assigns false to the condition and skips all the steps in the stage.

Comment: Can you share with us logs which shows evaluation of the formula?

Comment: `stageDependencies` is correct when you use this in condifion on job level. `dependencies` is for stage level conditions. Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> azure pipeline condition always returns false

That because you are using the **condition** on the stage level. Please try to using following condition:

```
 - stage: build
   dependsOn: determineChanges
   condition: eq(Dependencies.determineChanges.outputs['checkChanges.check_changes.SOURCE_CODE_CHANGED'], 'true')
```

Please note that we need update the stages refer from `stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']` To `Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']`

And not use the variable for the value `Dependencies.determineChanges.outputs['checkChanges.check_changes.SOURCE_CODE_CHANGED']`

My test result:

```
stages:
  - stage: stageA
    jobs:
    - job: A
      pool:
        name: Default
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "create a variable"
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomVar;isOutput=true]true"                
        name: CustomVariable

  - stage: stageB
    dependsOn: stageA
    condition: eq(Dependencies.stageA.outputs['A.CustomVariable.CustomVar'], 'true')
    jobs:
    - job: A
      pool:
        name: Default
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "output the variable"
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
                  Write-Host "hello world"
```

[image]

Comment: came to the same result yesterday after countless hours of trying :) gonna mark this as the answer in case other people encounter the same problem